# Cannot get Alerts to show on iPhone no matter what way I code it and I have tried 4 different ways

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Of these 4 methods mentioned, they all work in the simulator, but non of them work on the iPhone. Here are the pieces of code that come into play here.

```
<ListView x:Name="AutoView" ItemsSource="{Binding AutoData}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" SeparatorVisibility="None"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" BackgroundColor="Purple">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <ViewCell.View>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="27"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="105"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="35"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="36"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="Medium" TextColor="White" Text="{Binding Year}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                            <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="Medium" TextColor="White" Text="{Binding Name}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"/>
                            <Switch x:Name="{Binding Id}" IsToggled="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" Toggled="Handle_Toggled" Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="0" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell.View>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

View Model code

```
    public AutoWithSwitch SelectedItem
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedItem;
        }
        set
        {
            _selectedItem = value;

            if (_selectedItem == null)
                return;
            DisplayAlerts(value);
        }
    }

    public async void DisplayAlerts(AutoWithSwitch value)
    {           
        Application.Current.Properties["DeleteData"] = value;            
        DependencyService.Get<IMessage>().LongAlert("Stupid");            
    }
```

Interface defined in the common project

```
public interface IMessage
{
    void ShowMsg(Mileage value);
    void LongAlert(string message);
    void ShortAlert(string message);
}
```

Code in iOS project to display the alert

```
    public void LongAlert(string message)
    {
        ShowAlert(message);
    }
    public void ShortAlert(string message)
    {
        ShowAlert(message);
    }

    void ShowAlert(string message)
    {
        UpdateCarsViewModel ucvm = new UpdateCarsViewModel();
        //alertDelay = NSTimer.CreateScheduledTimer(seconds, (obj) =>
        //{
        //    dismissMessage();
        //});
        alert = UIAlertController.Create(null, "Action", UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
        alert.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("Delete", UIAlertActionStyle.Default,UIAlertAction => ucvm.DeleteCar()));
        alert.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("Cancel", UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, null));
        UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.PresentViewController(alert, true, null);
    }
```

Again, this works in the simulator but on the iPhone it does absolutely nothing. Any help you could give me would be much appreciated. Thanks so much!

Comment: is there a reason you're not using Forms DisplayAlert or DisplayActionSheet?  And what debugging have you done?  Have you stepped through the code on an iPhone, or at least added some logging to determine what might be going wrong?

Comment: 1) Test on a simulator running *the same version of iOS* as your iPhone. That should behave exactly the same as the phone. 2) With iPhone connected to pc or mac, the VS Output pane might show some message whenever you try to bring up alert. If so, what does it say? 3) Is there some other difference in how you run on iPhone vs emulator? Maybe with/without Hot Restart? 4) I assume you are running Debug build on both.

Comment: 5) Delete the app from iPhone. Power off phone. Turn it back on, and launch app from pc/mac again. 6) Delete `bin` and `obj` folders in your app's iOS project. To force a thorough rebuild.

Comment: Well, took your advice and added debugging statements to my code and found that the SelectedItem method is not even firing. Any idea why that would happen?

Comment: Try to set binding mode as `TwoWay` in xaml , `SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem,Mode=TwoWay}"`

Comment: are you tapping on the row, or are you selecting the checkbox in the row?

Comment: I am tapping on the row. And thanks for the response, but adding the Mode=TwoWay did not help

Comment: It's weird, your code looks no problem , would you mind sharing a basic ,reproducible project to us for test ? You can upload to github and attach the link here .

Comment: A test version of my code is located here, https://github.com/seattlesteve1999/MileageTest

Comment: Sorry , it seems something wrong with the project , I can't be able to build it , I suggest you use `ItemSelected` event instead of `SelectedItem` , you can get the current item via `e.SelectedItem` in code behind.

Comment: I deleted all my code from GitHub and readded it in the format needed. Please take a look and see if it will compile now. I have tried the ItemSelected as well and it is not working for me. That is not in the uploaded code, just on my computer, but please take a look, there has to be something going on that I just cannot see, https://github.com/seattlesteve1999/MileageTest  Thanks so much!

Comment: Hi , I test your code , it works without any problem , I see the same code was placed in `MainMenuViewModel` and `UpdateCarsViewModel` , and one of them shows the alert and another does not ,  did you mix them up or not ?  Also , I would suggest you just 
simply use `(App.Current as App).MainPage.DisplayAlert("","test","ok")` instead of calling depenpendcy service and see if problem persisits.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. That is right, I do not want to show an alert on the main menu, just on the update car page. When you say the code worked without any problem are you saying on the simulator or on a phone, because it works like a champ on the simulator, but not on my phone. All other functions are working but this SelectedItem or ItemSelected, both don't work on the phone. I could try the DisplayAlert again, but ran into an issue with it which I overcame with the new functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working using the ItemSelected that was recommended. Here is the code that worked.

The View

```
<ListView x:Name="AutoView" ItemsSource="{Binding AutoData}" ItemSelected="Selected" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" BackgroundColor="Purple">
```

The View code behind

```
void Selected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
     {
         if (Convert.ToBoolean(Application.Current.Properties["FirstSelected"]))
         {
             Application.Current.Properties["FirstSelected"] = false;
             //Analytics.TrackEvent("UpdateCar.xaml.cs - Select top");
             var ucvm = new UpdateCarsViewModel((AutoWithSwitch)e.SelectedItem);
             //Analytics.TrackEvent("UpdateCar.xaml.cs - Select top2" + (AutoWithSwitch)e.SelectedItem);

             if (e.SelectedItem == null)
             {                    
                 return;
             }
                
             AutoView.SelectedItem = null;                
         }
     }
```

The View Model

```
 public UpdateCarsViewModel(AutoWithSwitch data)
     {
         StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();
         // Get calling method name
         var methodName = stackTrace.GetFrame(1).GetMethod().Name;
         Analytics.TrackEvent("In UpdateCarsViewModel MethodName = " + methodName);
         if (methodName == "Selected")
         {
             DisplayAlerts(data);                
         }
     }

 public async void DisplayAlerts(AutoWithSwitch value)
     {           
         var answer = await (App.Current as App).MainPage.DisplayAlert("Action", "Delete", "Ok", "Cancel");
         if (answer)
             DeleteCar(value);
         else
             Application.Current.Properties["FirstSelected"] = true;            
     }
```

Thanks to everyone for all your help

Comment: Could you mark it as answer ?Thanks.